# Issue installing soundfile

Tags: python, installation, conda, environment, soundfile

I'm trying to install `soundfile` in a new conda environment. I've tried everything and I keep getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'soundfile'`.

On the same machine, I have an old conda environment where it works. If I type `pip show soundfile` I get:

```
Name: SoundFile
Version: 0.10.3.post1
Summary: An audio library based on libsndfile, CFFI and NumPy
Home-page: https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundFile
Author: Bastian Bechtold
Author-email: basti@bastibe.de
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: cffi
Required-by:
```

The strange thing is that this is the output I get in the new conda environment (it's the same!):

```
Name: SoundFile
Version: 0.10.3.post1
Summary: An audio library based on libsndfile, CFFI and NumPy
Home-page: https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundFile
Author: Bastian Bechtold
Author-email: basti@bastibe.de
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: cffi
Required-by:
```

I cloned the old conda environment using

```
conda create --name NEWENV --file spec-file.txt
conda env update --name NEWENV --file environment.yml
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I really don't understand why `soundfile` it's not working in the new environment even though it is set up exactly the same way. Any insights?

Comment: Did you activate the new environment? `conda activate NEWENV`

Comment: Yes, I am in the new environment

Comment: How are you running the python code? Are you using the correct python interpreter?

Comment: I'm writing in the command line `python -c 'import soundfile'` and I get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'soundfile'``` whereas I don't get that in the old environment

Comment: Does everything look correct when you do `conda info` - e.g., the env name, location, etc.?

Comment: Yes, everything looks correct

Comment: And `conda list` shows the package?

Comment: `pip freeze` shows it... conda won't show it because `soundfile` is not available for a `conda install`

Comment: That should not matter. I just installed `SoundFile` with pip and it appears when I do `conda list` I am going to guess it is not installed correctly. Try removing the package from your new env and reinstall it using `pip install SoundFile`

Comment: You're right, I see it in the old environment but not in the new environment. I just uninstalled and reinstalled in the new environment but it still doesn't show in `conda list`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243912/discussion-between-it-is-chris-and-the-dummy).